# Crontab : Running a jar file

Tags: unix, jar, scheduled-tasks, cron

I have a jar file that generates reports and i want to schedule to run it on every sunday,

For this purpose, i am using the crontab functionality on linux,

i have created the crontab entry using

```
     crontab -e
     45 15 * * 1 /usr/java/default/bin/java -jar /home/name/example/withouttimer.jar
```

but the job does not run as it should, Can you please help me find the issue with it,

Is there a way to check crontab logs?, thanks

Comment: Does your java program require X?

Comment: Add a MAILTO=«you» at the top of your crontab, so you get a mail with error messages.

Comment: Check where cron log goes in `man cron`. Redirect the output of your command in crontab by appending `2>&1 > /home/name/cron.out`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution,

There was a couple of things that i was doing incorrectly,

1. The timezone of the server was different, so i had to set it accordingly.
2. The jar was not able to locate the input file(bad location), had to fix it.

Works gr8 now, thanks for the suggestion on adding MAILTO= , helped in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the profile used when running cron jobs does not have some variables set (JAVA_HOME? CLASSPATH?)

Do a crontab that does `printenv > myfile.txt` and check what is defined.

---

As a last test, create a .sh file and run it, that does

```
echo 'hello'
printenv
echo 'goodbye'
```

and see if redirecting the execution of your script to a log shows something.

Comment: Even the crontab with printenv > myfile.txt does not work, Now i am wondering if there is any issue with crontab itself..  java is set in the env variables, i did check it up

Answer (score 0):

That job runs at 3:45 pm on every monday (0 is for sunday)Are you sure you are checking it at right time?

Try running a dummy program at lesser interval to check whether its working.